# How to use multiple values in React-table Cell?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have this in my code:

```
{
    Header: "Amount",
    accessor: "reward_amount",
    Cell: ({ value }) => `$${value / 100.0}`,
}
```

So `value` is `reward_amount`, but I also need to look at another value on the row data in order to determine what the cell content should be.

Here's more of the code:

```
export default function myFunc(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(props.stuff);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(props.stuff);
  }, [props.stuff]);

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      ...
      {
        Header: "Amount",
        accessor: "reward_amount",
        Cell: ({ value }) => `$${value / 100.0}`,
      },
      ...
    ],
    []
  );

  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable(
      {
        columns,
        data,
      },
      useRowSelect
    );

  return (...);
}
```

Comment: You mean like `Cell: ({ value, anotherValue }) => value + anotherValue`?

Comment: @rayhatfield does that work? It doesn't make sense to me because `value` is `reward_value`, ie. it's a different variable name. So I don't think I can access other values on the row like that.

Comment: You can pass a function to `accessor` that gets the whole row as a prop.

Comment: @Ryan I'm not familiar with react-table, but at a glance it appears that the `Cell` function receives the row as an argument, and you're destructuring `value` from it. If you need additional properties from the row you should be able to destructure those too. Your current implementation is the equivalent of `(row) => ${row.value / 100.0}`.

Answer (score 2):

The row data can be accessed by using **row.original** object.

```
{
    Header: "Amount",
    Cell: ({ row }) => `$${row.original.reward_amount / 100.0}`,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the answers. For me, it works:

```
{
    header: "ID",
    cell: (props) => (<React.Fragment>
            {props.row.original.serverId}  
            {props.row.original.locationCode}
        </React.Fragment>)
}
```

And what is important that inside the table you should use:

```
flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())
```

not just *cell.getValue()*

I hope it helps someone!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35721055)